# Error While Running python code into C# , please how to solve it?

Tags: python, c#

Hey everyone I'm trying to run script python into c# as I'm a beginner but I got this error
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected token 'from''

My C# code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void run_cmd(string cmd)
    {

        try
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
            paths.Add(@"C:\Users\emady\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages");
            paths.Add(@"C:\Users\emady\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib");
            engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            scope.SetVariable(cmd,typeof(string));
            engine.ExecuteFile("C:\\Users\\emady\\Desktop\\test_file.py",scope);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "test");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        run_cmd("ahmed");
    }
}
```

}

and my python code is

```
import cv2
def func(name):
f = open('C:\\Users\\emady\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\venv\\' + name + '.txt', 
'w')
f.write('test')
```

But I don't know how to solve it
[The full Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cDMt.png)

and the error by details I don't know how to solve it please help

```
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException
HResult=0x80131500
  Message=unexpected token 'from'
  Source=IronPython
  StackTrace:
   at IronPython.Runtime.ThrowingErrorSink.Add(SourceUnit sourceUnit, String message, SourceSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Severity severity)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Int32 start, Int32 end, String message, Int32 errorCode)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Token t, IndexSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Boolean allowIncomplete)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParsePrimary()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParsePower()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFactor()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpr(Int32 precedence)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseComparison()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseNotTest()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseAndTest()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseOrTest()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpression()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExpressionList(Boolean& trailingComma)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseYieldExpression()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseYieldStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSmallStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSimpleStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseIfStmtTest()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseIfStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseLoopSuite()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseForStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseIfStmtTest()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseIfStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassOrFuncBody()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFuncDef()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFileWorker(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFile(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ParseAndBindAst(CompilerContext context)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompilePythonCode(SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.GetScriptCode(SourceUnit sourceCode, String moduleName, ModuleOptions options, CompilationMode mode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run1[T0,TRet](T0 arg0)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.InitializeModule(String fileName, ModuleContext moduleContext, ScriptCode scriptCode, ModuleOptions options)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileModule(String fileName, String moduleName, SourceUnit sourceCode, ModuleOptions options, ScriptCode& scriptCode)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadModuleFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadPackageFromSource(CodeContext context, String name, String path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.LoadFromDisk(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, String str)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPathHook(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path, Func`5 defaultLoader)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportFromPath(CodeContext context, String name, String fullName, List path)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportTopAbsolute(CodeContext context, String name)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportModule(CodeContext context, Object globals, String modName, Boolean bottom, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Modules.Builtin.__import__(CodeContext context, String name, Object globals, Object locals, Object fromlist, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Importer.ImportLightThrow(CodeContext context, String fullName, PythonTuple from, Int32 level)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ImportTop(CodeContext context, String fullName, Int32 level)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`4.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget(Scope scope)
   at IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run(Scope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(String path, ScriptScope scope)
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.run_cmd(String cmd) in C:\Users\emady\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 26
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\emady\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 46
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.run_cmd(string) in Form1.cs
    WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Form1_Load(object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
    [External Code]
```

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve sorry dude how to get that? i attached screen isn't enough?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code in your question. I assumed `from` was on line 418 of your python file. So you are saying that `C:\\Users\\emady\\Desktop\\test_file.py` is just those few lines that you showed in question? If you comment out `engine.ExecuteFile ...` line, does it still give the error? **If so,** need to step through the lines of code, find out which one gives the error. **If not,** I'm not sure what is failing, sorry. Based on that code, it would have to be `import cv2` that is failing to be parsed - must bring in 418 or more lines. I don't know why that import would fail.

Comment: I see the call stack mentions import. So somehow `cv2` isn't compatible with your environment. Hmm, have you used it with `IronPython` before?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeh that simple code :D i just testing how to run python code with c# so I began with two lines to discover the errors faster :D

Comment: ok, depends on what your goal is. `IronPython` is better integrated with .Net, BUT isn't 100% compatible with all cpython code. An alternative is [`Python.NET`](http://pythonnet.github.io/). This is a fully compliant cpython port - but it isn't as convenient to make .NET calls from. Unfortunately there is no "perfect" answer, so you have to pick one or the other. Which approach sounds closer to what you need?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i need to make ocr and use it into my c# code? i even tried to make my code as dll and I import into c# but didn't know how to do that?

Comment: I just want to reiterate the important part of this, in case it isn't clear.  When you call `Python.CreateEngine`, that's not calling the Python command-line interpreter that you know and love.  It is a different implementation called IronPython which generates .NET intermediate language instead of Python byte codes.  It has its own standard library.  It uses .NET assemblies, not DLLs. You can't just add your Python 3.10 library to the search path; you don't even know if the IronPython is 3.10.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes pleaseeeee

Comment: Your example should work as-is if you remove the `paths.Add` calls.  IronPython knows the location of its own standard library.  But that's not going to help you call `cv2`.  CV2 runs in a Python DLL (.pyd) file, and IronPython doesn't do those.  You can always call your Python script using `System.Diagnostics.Process`, but then of course it won't be part of your app.  On the other hand, OpenCV is available for C# (https://www.emgu.com/), so it may be time for a port.

Comment: I finally found mention of C# calling Python in [`python.net`](http://pythonnet.github.io/). Near bottom of that page, find section "Passing C# Objects to the Python Engine". Also, see [Installation instructions here](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by clearing import cv2 this line
and I edited my c# code as that

```
    var var1 = "samy";
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    engine.ExecuteFile("C:\\Users\\emady\\Desktop\\test_file.py", 
    scope);
    dynamic testFunction = scope.GetVariable("func");
    var result = testFunction(var1);
```

but why my line didn't write('test')??

Comment: Please keep follow-up questions out of your answers.